# JPA criteria query for company and its employee count

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I am using JPA repositories. I have a Company table with one-to-many relationship with Employee table. I want to get list of companies with employee count who's last name is x. I am trying to use multiselect but the count is not getting populated. Here is what I am trying to do.

```
public class CompanyEntity {
    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "company", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<EmployeeEntity> employees;

    @Transient
    private Integer employeeCount;
}
```

...

```
@Autowired
private CompanyRepository repo;
```

...

```
public Page<CompanyEntity> findAllCompanies(Pageable pageable, String lastname) {

    Specification<CompanyEntity> specification = (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        Join employees = root.join("employees");
        criteriaQuery.groupBy(root);
        criteriaQuery.multiselect(root, criteriaBuilder.count(employees).alias("employeeCount"));

        Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(employees.get("lastname"), lastname);
        return predicate;
    };

    Page<EmployeeEntity> page = repo.findAll(specification, pageable);

    return page;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the count value supposed to go?

A `Specification` just configures the where part of a query.

If you want to control the full query including the select list do a [custom method implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior) and use the `EntityManager` directly.

Comment: I thought `multiselect` in the above code would select count.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a query on repository method.

```
@Query("select c, count(e.id) from company c left join employee e on c.id = e.company.id where e.lastname = :lastname group by c.id")
Page<Object[]> findAll(@Param("lastname") String lastname, Pageable pageable);
```

Here `Object[0]` contains `CompanyEntity` and `Object[1]` contains count as `Long`.